# How to fix Invalid destructuring assignment target?

Tags: javascript

What I can do in order to fix my problem? I'm a new newbie in javascript and any recomendations or advices could be helpful to me.

```
var user = {
    username: "Andrey",
    password: "JavaScript"
    },
    {
    username: "Max",
    password: "12345"
    },
    {
    username: "Pasha",
    password: "OWL"
    };

var database = [user];

var newsfeed = [
    {
        username: "Bobby",
        timeline: "DOOOOOOG!",
    },
    {
        username: "Max",
        timeline: "CAAAAT!",
    },
    {
        username: "Lida",
        timeline: "John Ceeeenaaaa!",
    }
];

var userNamePrompt = prompt("Your Username?");
var passwordPrompt = prompt("Your password?");

function isUserValid(Name, Pass){
    for (var i=0; i<database.length; i++){
        if (database[i].username === Name &&
            database[i].password === Pass) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;   
}

function SignIn (Name, Pass){
    if (isUserValid(Name, Pass)) {
        console.log(newsfeed);
    }
    else {
        alert("Sorry smt went wrong!");
    }
}

SignIn (userNamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

If the code is working correctly, i should get back an array with a newsfeed, but instead im getting:
Invalid destructuring assignment target

Comment: On which line you are getting that error. Please put a comment above it

Comment: I'm getting it on the line:
    username: "Max",
in the variable user

Comment: There is no "first array" - the `var user = /* ... */` simply has three objects listed but not in an array. That's invalid syntax

Comment: That is just a typo wrap user in `[]`. `var user = [
    {
    username: "Andrey",
    password: "JavaScript"
    },
    {
    username: "Max",
    password: "12345"
    },
    {
    username: "Pasha",
    password: "OWL"
    }
]`

Comment: Your `user` has incorrect syntax, take a look at correct `newsfeed`, fix `user` and remove `database` (or remove `user` and copy these objects into `[ ]` in `database` assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote: `var user = { property }{ property }{ property }` which doesn't work. This is probably what you meant ( also skips the `var database = [ user ];` assignment):

```
var database = [
    {
      username: "Andrey",
      password: "JavaScript"
    },
    {
      username: "Max",
      password: "12345"
    },
    {
      username: "Pasha",
      password: "OWL"
    }
]
```